# Slow Numba performance on convolution

Tags: python, convolution, numba

I am using the following code for the convolution between components of two 3D arrays using Numba:

```
@jit( nopython=True, parallel=True, nogil=True )
def calculate_convs_products( x_grid, fn, gn, indices_pairs_array):
           
    total_items  = fn.shape[1]
    total_points = x_grid.shape[0]
    
    #result       = []
    final_res    = np.zeros( (fn.shape[1],fn.shape[-1]), dtype=fn.dtype )    
    

    #indices_pairs_array is an array of the type [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1], 
    #                                              [1,2]...]
    #with all N**2 pairings of N integers from 0 to N-1.
    tot_pairs    = indices_pairs_array.shape[0]
    
    for l in prange( tot_pairs ):
        
        f   = fn[indices_pairs_array[l,0]]
        g   = gn[indices_pairs_array[l,1]]
        
        
        result       = []
        for k in range( total_items ): 
            res_k = []
            for x_i in range( total_points ):
                index = x_i - int( total_points/2 )
                gs    = np.roll( g[k,:],  index )
                if ( index < 0 ):                
                    gs[ index: ]    = g[ k, -1 ] 
                elif ( index > 0 ):               
                    gs[ 0:index ]   = g[ k, 0 ]                      
                           
                res = trapzl( f[ k, : ]*gs , x_grid )            
                res_k.append( res )
            
            result.append( res_k )
        
        result     = np.array( result )
        final_res += result 
        
           
    return final_res   

@jit( nopython=True )
def trapzl(y, x):
    "Pure python version of trapezoid rule."
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        s += (x[i]-x[i-1])*(y[i]+y[i-1])
    return s/2
```

Note that the arrays `fn` and `gn` that enter the function are 3D, and the convolution takes place respect to the last axis. However, I am having really bad performance using the above implementation. In addition, Numba is not parallelizing correctly the external `l` loop. What could be slowing this down and how can we make it more efficient?

Comment: maybe dumb questions, but, what do you call "slow"? have you compared to no @jit use?  have you only run the call one time? Also if you could provide one example data o sample data sizes could be great to tests

Comment: Slow as compared to a standard serialized Python code, which seems to do this much faster.

Comment: Can you add a example of input arrays which are slow (eg. possibly random ones)? Or at least a call with valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot parallelize the loop the way you do because it should result in a **race condition**. Indeed, the shared array `final_res` is read and written by multiple threads. In Numba, threads need to work on different memory regions array or alternatively read a memory regions that are left untouched by other threads. Otherwise, a synchronization is mandatory (AFAIK, Numba does not provide advanced ways to synchronize thread since it is based on a simple fork-join model, so multiple parallel loops should be required in such a case).

Note the `k`-based and the `x_i`-based loop cannot be trivially parallelized using `prange` too because of the `append` calls and parallelizing `trapzl` should not be efficient since the time taken by this function should likely be small (and sending work to threads is expensive). Thus, this means the code cannot be trivially parallelized efficiently.

Note that in Numba all variable are typed and they can only have 1 unique type. The thing is `result` is initialized as a typed list and you do `result = np.array( result )` which means that it should also be an `np.array`. Even though such a line could work, it would introduce a silly inefficient implicit conversion. You can fix that using another variable name. I expect Numba to complain that the code cannot be compiled (resulting in a pure-Python execution).

Hopefully, the sequential code can be improved. First of all, you do not need to use (slow) lists since you know the loop iteration ranges. You can directly create the array `result` with the good size `(total_items, total_points)` and fill it. In fact, you can even not create the array since it is only used to accumulate some values in `final_res`. You can directly accumulate the values in `final_res` if it has the same size than `result` (ie. no broadcasting).

Finally, note that the Numba function will be lazily compiled during the first execution of the function. This can impact your benchmark since compiling such a function will probably be quite slow compared to its execution time. You can specify the input type by providing the signature of the function so Numba can compile it eagerly (see [here](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/types.html) for more information).

There is probably many more optimizations that can be applied but it is hard to tell without some valid input values (especially the input types).